# Search labelled changes which are not dev-released in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I have a VOB with 4 labels. 3 of them are `dev-released`.
I want a command which will give me the changed files only for the fourth label, i.e. files which are not yet `dev-released`.

I tried the following command:

```
cleartool find . -version lbtype(LABEL_NAME) -print
```

But this is giving me all the files which which are labeled in that VOB, irrespective of whether they are `dev-released` or not.

Please could anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You would need first to find all the versions which:

- have the right label
- have the right attribute

That would be a query similar to:

```
cleartool find . -type f -version "lbtype(LABEL_NAME) && yourAttribute=\"dev-released\"" -print
```

Replace '`yourAttribute`' with the name of your attribute which has amonst its values '`dev-released`'.

You can see other examples in the technote "[Listing out element versions with a specific attribute applied](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21226503)".

If `dev-released` is not an attribute value, but an attribute *type*:

```
cleartool find . -type f -version "lbtype(LABEL_NAME) && attype(dev-released)" -print
```

---

> how I could find out the attributes of a label and the attribute types

That could be interpreted as finding the attributes applied on *labelled* versions:

Windows syntax:

```
cleartool find . -type f -version "lbtype(LABEL_NAME)" -exec "cleartool descr -aattr -all \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But what I need is the command which is run on click of the "Search labeled changes" option that we get on right-clicking on a VOB. Do you know which script is run for this?

Comment: I need the command which is run on click of the "Search labeled changes" option that we get on right-clicking on a VOB. Do you know which script is run for this?

Comment: @JahnaviK.Abhyuday can you add (by editing your question) a screenshot of that contextual menu as displayed on a vob?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not allowed to add a screenshot :(  Sorry :(

Comment: Or could you please let me know how I could find out the attributes of a label and the attribute types.

Comment: @JahnaviK.Abhyuday you can post your screenshot elsewhere and just add a link to it. I will edit your question to add the picture.

Comment: I tried the above command and I got the following error -"Object Selector Require".

Comment: @JahnaviK.Abhyuday can you copy-paste in your question the exact command and the exact error message?

Comment: @JahnaviK.Abhyuday Are you on Windows? on Unix? Which version of ClearCase are you using?

Comment: The command I used is : cleartool find . -type f -version "lbtype(LABEL_NAME)" -exec "cleartool descr -aattr \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""

Comment: cleartool: Error: Object selector required.
Usage: describe -graphical pname ...
       describe [-local] [-long | -short | -fmt format]
            [-alabel {label-type-selector[,...] | -all}]
            [-aattr {attr-type-selector[,...] | -all}]
            [-ahlink {hlink-type-selector[,...] | -all}]
              { [-cview] [-version version-selector | -ancestor]
                [-ihlink {hlink-type-selector[,...] | -all}]
                [-predecessor] [-pname] [-aliases [-all]] pname ...
              | -type type-selector ...
              | -cact | object_selector ...
              }

Comment: @JahnaviK.Abhyuday can you try with `-all`? That is: `descr -aattr -all \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\"` instead of `descr -aattr \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\"`